# Метод remove() у ArrayList не умеет работать с переменными?

Tags: android, массивы, android-studio, arraylist

Есть массив EditText-ов.
Если указывать индекс его методу remove() напрямую - элемент удаляется;
Если указывать индекс через переменную - Не удаляется.

На картинке нагляднее показано.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: оформите код в виде текста, а не скриншотом. Что делать, если [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 6):

Дело не в переменной, а в том, что есть два метода: `remove(int index), remove(Object o)`. Если передавать целочисленную константу или переменную типа `int`, то сработает первый. Если передавать `Integer`, то это уже объект и сработает второй метод.

Таким образом в Вашей коллекции просто не будет найден объект по ссылке `num` и ничего не произойдет.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответ)

Answer (score -1):

Всё просто.
В качестве индекса используй примитивный тип (не `Integer`, а `int`):

```
int num = 2;
massiv.remove(num);
```

В таком случае, ArrayList будет считать его индексом, а не объектом (как например Integer).

Comment: Не понимаю, кто может минусовать, если ответ верный (=.=)

Comment: Это голос против от _системы_ (да-да, от самого движка). По его мнению, ответ низкого качества. Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ больше подробностей и обоснований.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать)

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky, интересно было бы посмотреть код движка :)